# joint distribution: $P(X_{t}|X_{t-1},y)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume the following discrete time state space model

$X_{t}=AX_{t-1}+W$

$y_{t}=CX_{t}+V$

w and v are assumed to be zero mean i.i.d. white noise with bounded covariance matrices  and ℎ.

How can I find $P(X_{t}|X_{t-1},y_{t})$?

Comment: How is $(W,V)$ distrbuted?

Comment: W and V have Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general

$$P( B  \mid  A C ) = \frac{P ( B C  \mid  A) }{P(C  \mid  A)}= \frac{P ( B C  \mid  A) }{\int P(BC \mid A)dB} $$

But $P ( B C  \mid  A)=P(C  \mid  B A) P(B \mid A)$.

Furthermore , if $A \to B \to C$ (that is, if $P(C \mid BA)=P(C \mid B)$, i.e. the sequence is Markovian), then it gives $P ( B C  \mid  A) = P(C \mid B) P(B \mid A)$

In our case ($A=X_{t-1}$, $B=X_t$, $C=y_t$ - check that they are indeed Markovian) we get

$$P(X_{t} \mid X_{t-1},y_{t})=\frac{P(y_t  \mid  X_t) P( X_t \mid X_{t-1})}{\int P(y_t  \mid  X_t) P( X_t \mid X_{t-1}) dX_t }$$

Of course, if you regard $X_t$ as the variable, the denominator is just a normalization constant.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: you're welcome - see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers